# Create a dict from two lists of dicts with matching value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries, `dict1` and `dict2`.

```
dict1 = [
  {
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'James'
  }, {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Bob'
  }
]

dict2 = [
  {
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'James'
  }, {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'James'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Bob'
  }
]
```

And i want to create a dict like that:

```
result = {'James': [0, 1], 'Bob': [2]}
```

With the names from `dict1` as keys and as value the list of `"id"` fields having the same name.

What's a clean way to do that in Python?

Comment: I'm assuming the `'id'` values should only come from `dict2`?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, I believe last line should be `Bob` and not `James`. That way, using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)

>>> df2.groupby('name').agg(list).to_dict()['id']
{'Bob': [2], 'James': [0, 1]}
```

To filter only `names` that are in `dict1`,

```
>>> df2 = df2[df2['name'].isin(df1['name'])]
```

and `group` and `agg` after that

Comment: Supposing the entry `dict2[2]` is Bob and not James, you are missing the value 1 for Bob, as it is in `dict1[1]`

Comment: @TheWildHealer This is on purpose. Im using `keys` from `dict1` and `values` from `dict2`, which apparently meets OP's expected output after this edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the names in `dict1` in a set first, so that when you iterate over `dict2`, you can check if the current name is in the set before adding it to the resulting dict of lists:

```
names = {d['name'] for d in dict1}
result = {}
for d in dict2:
    if d['name'] in names:
        result.setdefault(d['name'], []).append(d['id'])
```

`result` becomes:

```
{'James': [0, 1], 'Bob': [2]}
```

Comment: `defaultdict` is an alternative. The OP asks for a dict as a result, and therefore I'm using `dict.setdefault`. Nothing wrong with either. And by the way you can't use `defaultdict` "right away" because you still do need to build a set from `dict1` first to test for name membership.

Comment: When I meant right away was to avoid calling `.setdefault` at every iteration, which seems unnecessarily wordy. `result = defaultdict(list)` and return `dict(result)` sounded better. But of course, nothing wrong with it :}

Comment: Yes, it's fine either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in pure Python as following:

```
dict1 = [
  {
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'James'
  }, {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Bob'
  }
]


dict2 = [
  {
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'James'
  }, {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'James'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Bob'
  }
]

names = [elem['name'] for elem in dict1]
result = dict((name,[]) for name in names)
for elem in dict2:
    result[elem['name']].append(elem['id'])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'James': [0, 1], 'Bob': [2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here's a `defaultdict` solution:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> result = defaultdict(list)
>>> names = {d['name'] for d in dict1}
>>> 
>>> for d in dict2:
...:    name = d['name']
...:    if name in names:
...:        result[name].append(d['id'])
...:        
>>> result
defaultdict(list, {'Bob': [2], 'James': [0, 1]})
```